# How to switch between horizontal and vertical split in vimdiff on Mac?

Tags: macos, vim

I first do a vimdiff on two files, but they are vertically split, which makes it hard to read. I want to switch to horizontal split. I tried:

control + w then J or h, which doesn't effect at all

I also tried:
command + w, which asked 'Do you want to terminate processes in this tab?'

I got stuck here. What's wrong with me?

Comment: ctrl+w, then capital H,J,K, or L will rotate the panels in different ways, including switching between horizontal and vertical

Comment: Why it doesn't work on my macpro? no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regular diff, `$ vim -d foo bar`, with the `foo` window active:

[image: diff]

Here is how it looks after pressing `<C-w>J`, that is `Control+w` then `Shift+j`:

[image: diff below]

Notice the active window is now at the bottom.

From the same starting point, here is how it looks after pressing `<C-w>K`, that is `Control+w` then `Shift+k`:

[image: diff above]

Notice the active window is now at the top.

See `:help window-moving`.

Answer (score 1):

To split the screen horizontally:
a.) Hit CTRL + w
b.) and then s.

If you want to navigate between the screen:
a.) Hit CTRL + w
b.) and then w.

To exit out of one of the screen:
a.) Go into command mode (i.e. hit ESC)
b.) and quit as usual: :q.

To split the screen vertically, much like splitting horizontally:
a.) Start by hitting CTRL + w.
b.) but then hit v (instead of s).

Navigating between the split screens is the same (CTRL + w + w).

Comment: ctrl + w +s did split horizontally, howver, it splits the same file into two panes. What I want is that, given file1 and file2 in two vertical windows, I want to see the two windows horizontal. If it splits the same file, it is not that useful. How to do that?

Comment: Also, is there a way to vimdiff file1 files with horizontal split at the command line initially, instead of the default vertical split?

Comment: I updated my question. I am using the vimdiff command to see the diffs in two files. I want to see the diffs horizonally.